# Numerical Integration: Why isn't Polynomial Approximation Working?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, approximation-theory, chebyshev-function

I have the following integration problem:

$$ \int_0^1{ -m f(x) \left(\int_0^x{f(u)} du \right)}^{m-1} dx $$

I attempted to approximate $ \int_0^x{f(u)} du  $ using Chebyshev interpolation, I took $n+1$ Chebyshev nodes and calculated $ \int_0^{x_i}{f(u)} du  $, where $x_i$ is the $i$th node. In the end, I had a polynomial $p(x) \approx \int_0^x{f(u)} du$. I used this polynomial to re-write the integral as

$$ \int_0^1{ -m f(x) \left(p(x) \right)}^{m-1}  dx $$

This integral approximation was incorrect, and far from what it should have been for different values of $m$. My error for $p(x)$ appeared to be very small.

I should note, that $f(x)$ represents a probability density function, and that the gradient of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0 $ is $\infty$. My approximation $p(x)$ is therefore an approximation of the corresponding cumulative density function.

Can someone explain why this approximation didn't work - if my approximation $p(x)$ has negligible error, would it have worked?

Comment: I'm curious why you are trying to approximate the integral at this stage since it has an exact form $$\int_0^1-mf(x)\left(\int_0^xf(u)du\right)^{m-1}dx = - \left(\int_0^1f(u)du\right)^m$$

Comment: Is there a reason a standard quadrature rule wouldn’t suffice?